# Is my query built correctly to produce the intended result?

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains userid, companyid, model. Data can look something like this:

```
userid      companyid    model
 1            800         A
 1            800         B
 2            232         A
 3            400         B
 4            900         A
 4            900         B
```

I want to return all rows where a user is in a company and has both models A and B. So based on my table I would want to return

```
userid          companyid   model
1                800         A
1                800         B
4                900         A
4                900         B
```

I think my query is working correctly. Could anyone verify that it is correct and should produce the intended result?

```
  SELECT  userid, model, companyid
  FROM table
  GROUP BY userid, model, companyid
  HAVING   COUNT(model) > 1 AND COUNT(companyid) = 1 
  ORDER BY userid, model, companyid
```

Comment: Does the user have both models or the company?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm trying to check to see if any user has both models for the same companyid.

Answer (score 0):

One method is `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t t
where t.model in ('A', 'B') and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.companyid = t.companyid and
                    t2.model in ('A', 'B') and
                    t2.model <> t.model
             );
```

This above is assumes the company needs to have both models.  If you want the user to have both models, then use `t2.userid = t.userid` in the correlation clause.

Comment: I'm getting an invalid object name on the t in the 5th line (from t)

Comment: @Rich . . . That is whatever your table name is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytical function as follows:

```
Select * from
(Select t.*, count(distinct model) over (partirion by user_id, company_id) as cnt
  From t
 Where t.model in ('A', 'B')) t
Where cnt = 2
```